# Possible Bug: Facebook Events API eid table values being returned with decimal points raw

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-events

I built a custom wordpress widget months ago that just pulls a users facebook events, styles and shows it in the sidebar. The events are still showing up fine -  except that the links now go to an facebook error page. So I checked the echo'd url and this is what I got :

https://www.facebook.com/events/4.3772330960996E+14

Obviously the url, ending at events/ is hard-coded and the number that follows is an echo is  a for loop. Which has been working clean for about 6mo.

At first I thought maybe it was returning an Integer that was being converted somehow.. but I checked the actual event id from facebook.com and this is what is was:

437723309609959

I think fb api is putting a decimal point where it had never been before.

Just to clarify: I am using PHP - using FQL through the GRAPH with CURL. And then echoing the raw row info.

Thoughts?

Comment: What is your php.ini setting for `precision`?

Comment: I don't have access to the server's main php.ini file. I suppose I could create one for the affected directory to test your theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `precision` setting in php.ini, or directly in code:

```
ini_set('precision', 20);
```

Answer (score 0):

You must be using a 32-bit version of PHP, where the largest integer is 2147483647

Try using [printf](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php) instead of echo:

```
printf('http://graph.facebook.com/events/%s', $eid);
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I tried your method and it returned the same value as when I tried (int) and intval. http://graph.facebook.com/events/1717711072

Comment: Try changing `%d` above to `%s`. I just looked through an events scraper I wrote for a site of mine and using that code works. I've got 32-bit PHP, and 15-character long `eid` strings are rendering correctly. On my server, `ini_get('precision')` = 14.