# How to add two large fractions in PHP

Tags: php, math

I want to add following numbers

```
$res = 0.000000002 + 0.000000002 + 0.000000002;
```

I got result like this

```
4.2E-8
```

can any one explain , how to get 0.000000006

thanks

Comment: Try using printf() rather than echo

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13320227/258674

Comment: If you want `0.000000006` as result, you should get `6.0E-9`. `4.2E-8` means `0.000000042`

Comment: I used printf( 0.000000002 +  0.000000002 + 0.000000002); result is same, i want to show exact result like 0.000000006

Comment: 4.2E-8 is just as exact.

Comment: You shouldn't have got the same result if you used `printf( 0.000000002 + 0.000000002 + 0.000000002);`; if anything, you should have got a warning.... printf() requires a format mask as the first argument

Answer (score 2):

You should get the following result:

```
echo 0.000000002 + 0.000000002 + 0.000000002;

6.0E-9
```

Which means you haven't told us the truth.

One way to get `4.2E-8` is to add `0.00000002 + 0.00000002 + 0.000000002;` (I removed a zero from two of them).

Comment: + Not the solution but valid point

Answer (score 2):

```
//Try using 
echo number_format($res,10);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$res = 0.000000002 + 0.000000002 + 0.000000002;
printf("%0.9f",$res);
```

or

```
print(number_format($res,9));
```

Output

```
0.000000006
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this .

```
$res = 0.000000002 + 0.000000002 + 0.000000002;

    echo number_format($res, 9, '.', '');die;
```

here 9 no is describe after dot how many digit you want to show.

Comment: your code is correct ! but value 9 does not remain the same all time, is any way to replace number 9 to a variable

Answer (score -1):

```
$res = 0.0000000002 + 0.0000000002 + 0.0000000002;
    echo exp2dec($res);

    function exp2dec($number) {
            preg_match('/(.*)E-(.*)/', str_replace(".", "", $number), $matches);
            $num = "0.";
            while ($matches[2] > 0) {
                    $num .= "0";
                    $matches[2]--;
            }
            return $num . $matches[1];
    }

    die;
```

Please try this.