# Adding numbers with decimal points in large quantity in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

i am trying adding numbers like this

```
$ctr = 0.0000001 + 0.0000001+ 0.0000001+ 0.0000001+ 0.0000001+ 0.0000001; 
echo floatval($ctr);
```

it gives result like this `2.0E-5`

i have tried, number_format, round etc... but result is same, it should be 0.0000006

please help me to make this happened.

Comment: I hope it doesn't give you 2.0E-5 as a result, but rather 6.0E-7

Comment: Ignoring the spurious cast to float ($ctr already is a float); look at using [sprint()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) if you want to display all the digits, otherwise live with the [scientific notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation) that numbers default to using if there are lots of digits

Comment: Why is this question tagged [tag:mysql] and [tag:mathematica]?

Comment: Duplicate of [How to add two large fractions in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17249130/how-to-add-two-large-fractions-in-php)

Comment: `printf("%0.7f",$ctr);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can try [BCMath](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.bc.php) as it advertises:

> For arbitrary precision mathematics PHP offers the Binary Calculator which supports numbers of any size and precision, represented as strings

A sample code:

```
$sum = bcadd('0.0000001','0.0000001',7); // 7 = num of digits after decimal point
echo $sum; // 0.0000002
```

Comment: Surely a bit overkill for the values that OP is working with... the problem seems to be a lack of understanding of scientific notation (e.g. basic mathematics)

Comment: @MarkBaker now I can see that aspect of this question :)

Comment: @user2341915 ``printf("%0.7f",$ctr);`` from @MarkBaker must be what you are looking for.